# What shell does -sh represent

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am new to hp-unix when I execute command echo $0 the output I get is -sh
I am not sure which shell it is.
If I execute echo $SHELL I get output as /sbin/sh

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow, it would be a better question for SuperUser. That said, sh is the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

Comment: It could be a reasonable question for UNIX.SE too, although it's already covered http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sh shell is the Bourne Shell, as cited by Sumner Evans.

If you need more information about it you can take a look at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

or

https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/